# VBA - copy (split) part of cell in one column into a new column

Tags: excel, parsing, split, copy, vba

I have the following date/time in `Column K`

```
Mon Nov 14 20:15:14 EST 2016
```

I'd like to copy the first 3 parts `'Mon Nov 14'` and add it to `column R` for all rows in a workbook with a variable file name.

`Column K` remains unchanged and it is always 10 characters. The date for less than 10 contains a leading 0.

Thanks so much for anyone able to help!

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering? Will using a formula solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Transfer()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim y As Integer
  Dim x As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "k").End(xlUp).Row
End With
y = 1

For x = 1 To LastRow
  range("k" & y).Select
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Left(range("k" & y), 10)
   y = y + 1
Next
End Sub
```